# Enable Verilog syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Can someone enable syntax highlighting for verilog and system-verilog code in SO?

Comment: Yes, we can. But if you want us to do so, you need to explain what *language* relates to those two tags and why it should be used for them. There is no "verilog" language in the syntax highlighting script.

Comment: `verilog` tag is associated with Verilog Hardware Description Language and `system-verilog` tag is associated with System Verilog Hardware Verification Language. There are a number of questions posted with verilog tag in SO. Syntax highlighting will make them more readable.

Comment: We don't have a Verilog syntax highlighter, so unless there's another language in the list that suits the code for these tags, there is nothing we can do.

Comment: I don't think so. It has a lot of unique keywords and syntax.